# Netbeans project won't rebuild with custom Ant target

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

Building a project in Netbeans. I have a single custom ANT Target in build.xml that copies two library files to dist/lib before the program runs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ApplicationName" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

<description>Builds, tests, and runs the project EnrollmentApplication.</description>

<import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <target name="-post-jar">
        <echo message="Copying dll files..." />
        <copy file="lib/file1.dll" todir="${dist.dir}/lib" />
        <copy file="lib/file2.dll" todir="${dist.dir}/lib" />
    </target>

</project>
```

However, when I make code changes, build, and run, the code changes aren't reflected in the new run. If I clean, rebuild, and run, I get `Error: Unable to access jarfile <file path>\Application1.jar`

Modifying build.xml manually at this point lets the project rebuild correctly **once**, and then the cycle starts over again. What am I misunderstanding about this Ant Target? It seems extremely straightforward.

EDIT:

Apparently copying files has nothing to do with it. Even overriding `-post-jar` with just the `<echo>` task yields the same problems

Comment: As you seem to have discovered already, the part of your script that you included in your question probably doesn't have much to do with the error you're running into. Can you post your entire script, or if it's too long, post the targets that build, deploy, and run your jar application? Putting the entire thing in a gist or pastebin would be fine too.

Comment: @CAustin - Full file posted. It's the standard Netbeans-generated build.xml with no other modifications. If I comment out the target and leave everything else the same, it will build as you would expect

Answer (score 0):

After looking at nbproject/build-impl.xml, it was apparent that the `-post-jar` target had dependencies that I was not including in my overriding target. They are listed below (note that this is a JavaFX program).

```
<target depends="-jfx-copylibs,-rebase-libs,jfx-deployment" name="-post-jar">
```

I assume these other targets are only called because `-post-jar` lists them as dependencies, i.e. they are not called by any other target.